# "gcloud app deploy" hangs on "Building and pushing image for service"

Tags: google-app-engine

I suddenly can't deploy using `gcloud app deploy`.

It hangs on "Building and pushing image for service [default]". At that time, the Python process takes 99% CPU, and continues until the deploy times out. I've tried upgrading Python to no avail.

It occurs regardless of Google Appengine Project. Have tried installing different versions of gcloud CLI to no avail.

My teammates can deploy successfully using the same commands. Any ideas?

EDIT:

The app.yaml file:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 6
  disk_size_gb: 10

env_variables:
  ...
```

Output of my `gcloud app deploy verbosity=debug`: https://gist.github.com/bbarton/05b8ae514849a5731101afb5ae639357

Comment: for clarity are your teammates deploying successfully within the same project as you or in different projects?

Comment: @JackWotherspoon Yes, for them it works for any project. For mine, it works with none of the projects the team is on.

Comment: thanks for that, do you mind sharing the `app.yaml` you are trying to deploy with?

Comment: also might be worth trying to run `gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug` to see if that provides insights into the reason for hanging.

Comment: @JackWotherspoon Thanks--I've added the relevant parts of the app.yaml file (the rest is just ENV vars).

Comment: I'm currently running it with `verbosity=debug`. I'll post that too. My teammates are also getting the same errors but it's not affecting their deploys.

Comment: Here is the verbose output: https://gist.github.com/bbarton/05b8ae514849a5731101afb5ae639357

Comment: What are you trying to do inside the code? Can you provide your `app.js` file?

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: I cloned the source repository anew, and now it works. Baffling.